# Cannot load PHP's Event extension php_event.dll on Windows

Tags: php, pecl

I've been trying to load the PHP's Event extension on Windows, without success.

I have a Windows 10 Pro 64-bit installed, with PHP v7.1.19 x64 running on IIS. I downloaded the extension "[7.1 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64](https://pecl.php.net/package/event/2.4.1/windows)" from PECL, copied `php_event.dll` to the extension directory `C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\ext`, and added the extension in `php.ini` with `extension=php_event.dll`.

But when I run `phpinfo()` on my browser, the corresponding **event** section is not shown (i.e. the extension is not loaded by PHP).

I used [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to inspect `php_event.dll`'s dependencies. Every dependency seems to be fine except for `PHP7.DLL`, which appears in red (with warnings) as shown in the picture below; apparently some function calls are not resolved like `_convert_to_string`, `_ealloc`, among others. I don't know if this might be the root of the problem.

[image]

I also tried to load the "7.1 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x86" extension in PHP x86 just for comparison, but the problem persists. The only difference is that Dependency Walker shows the `PHP7.DLL` dependency as normal (without warnings).

I've also tried to load previous versions of the extension, but nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to make PHP to load this extension in this environment?

Comment: Have you restarted IIS? See https://superuser.com/questions/678994/how-to-restart-php-on-windows-unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-ssl

Comment: Yes. I've even restarted Windows, but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you edit the correct `php.ini` file? There's often more than one. The output of `phpinfo()` will tell you which configuration files are in use

Comment: Yes, I also did that. I know it because I tried to disable/enable other extensions and the corresponding changes are made to `phpinfo`'s output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sockets extension support must be enabled before the event extension can be installed.
The event extension must be loaded after the sockets extension

Comment: Yes, I should know from the results of Dependency Walker that php_sockets.dll was also an extension that must be loaded first. Thank you.